# Remove the first character of a string

Tags: python, string

I would like to remove the first character of a string.

For example, my string starts with a `:` and I want to remove that only. There are several occurrences of `:` in the string that shouldn't be removed.

I am writing my code in Python.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

**python 2.x**

```
s = ":dfa:sif:e"
print s[1:]
```

**python 3.x**

```
s = ":dfa:sif:e"
print(s[1:])
```

**both prints**

```
dfa:sif:e
```

Comment: If this is the accepted answer then the question should have been "how do I remove the first character of a string".

Comment: @Spaceghost: The OP states "Specifically I want to remove the first character."

Comment: You are right, I was just responding to the difference between the title and the body of the question.. In hindsight, should have spent the time getting coffee. :-)

Answer (score 52):

Your problem seems unclear. You say you want to remove "a character from a certain position" then go on to say you want to remove a particular character.

If you only need to remove the first character you would do:

```
s = ":dfa:sif:e"
fixed = s[1:]
```

If you want to remove a character at a particular position, you would do:

```
s = ":dfa:sif:e"
fixed = s[0:pos]+s[pos+1:]
```

If you need to remove a particular character, say ':', the first time it is encountered in a string then you would do:

```
s = ":dfa:sif:e"
fixed = ''.join(s.split(':', 1))
```

Comment: The last example could be more easily done using `s.replace(":", "", 1)`-

Answer (score 39):

Depending on the structure of the string, you can use [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
str = str.lstrip(':')
```

But this would remove all colons at the beginning, i.e. if you have `::foo`, the result would be `foo`. But this function is helpful if you also have strings that do not start with a colon and you don't want to remove the first character then.

Answer (score 14):

Just do this:

```
r = "hello"
r = r[1:]
print(r) # ello
```

Comment: Does this add anything to Sven's answer from 9 years earlier? Besides, double quotes around a simple string is overkill, just use single quotes. Others call this more 'pythonic'

Answer (score 2):

deleting a char:

```
def del_char(string, indexes):

    'deletes all the indexes from the string and returns the new one'

    return ''.join((char for idx, char in enumerate(string) if idx not in indexes))
```

it deletes all the chars that are in indexes; you can use it in your case with `del_char(your_string, [0])`