# How can i remove the first character from a StringIO object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I couldn't figure it out with the Python documentation, so maybe i can ask it here:

```
import StringIO
line = StringIO.StringIO()
line.write('Hello World')
```

Is there any method i can use, that will do what `line[1:]` would do on a string,
so `line.getvalue()` will return `ello World`?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to **call** `StringIO` to create an instance; `line = StringIO.StringIO()`. `.getvalue()` returns a string, why not slice *that*?

Comment: And this smells like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what are you trying to solve, *really*.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945548/removing-a-character-from-a-certain-position-in-a-string-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks for the editing the typo. I don't want to slice the returned string but instead modify what the StringIO object holds, so further access to it would be sans that first character. My problem is that line[1:] would erase StringIO's methods, i'm interested in only modifying the text that getvalue() would return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't figure out how to do it with `line.getvalue`, but you can use StringIO objects like normal file objects.  Just seek to byte 1 and read as you normally would.

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> line = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> line.write("Hello World")
>>> line.seek(0)
>>> print line.getvalue()
Hello World
>>> line.seek(1)
>>> print line.getvalue()
Hello World
>>> line.seek(1)
>>> print next(line)
ello World
>>> line.seek(1)
>>> print line.read()
ello World
```

Comment: Thanks! seek() and read() do exactly what i need. Is there a way to make it seek from the next character each time without using an index variable? seek(i), i = i + 1...

Comment: @VCake -- You can figure out your current position using `tell`.  you can seek from the current position by `seek(1,1)` (I think)

Comment: @mgilson: Yep, that's correct: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek  (the first number is the offset which can be negative, too; the second number indicates the seek-mode, where `1` sets "current stream position" as the "starting point") -- added in Python 3.1 (it does only work for BytesIO, though, and not for StringIO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981996/relative-seek-for-io-stringio-in-python3)

Answer (score 2):

The StringIO getvalue() function return the content as string, so this could be work:

```
content = line.getvalue()
print content[1:]
```

Comment: Slicing makes a copy of the string.