# relative seek for io.StringIO in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, stringio

I am trying to refactor a python 2 package for use with python-3.x. The package uses `StringIO.StringIO` under python 2 and makes some use of the object's relative seek method, with statements like `flob.seek(-1, 1)`. Unfortunately, the `seek` method of the corresponding `io.StringIO` object in python 3 does not support relative seeks, so the code raises

```
OSError: Can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks
```

when trying to execute that statement.

What is the best way to refactor modules containing these calls, given that I would like to be able to continue using the functions this appears in for file objects as well as (objects derived from) strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because [strings in Python 2 are renamed bytes in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), the code should use [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) in Python 3, which supports relative seeking.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue25190

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/69377

Comment: The linked issues point to a discussion to implement this, but I guess the progress has just stalled.