# Getting numbers after domicile

Tags: python

I try to get numbers after decimal. I tried `re.split` but it couldn't give me the expect output.

I need to convert the:

```
125.52  -->  52
15.2    -->  2
```

Comment: what's wrong with `string.split` ? `stri.split('.')[1]`

Comment: Yes, it was asked before. but there, the result is the numbers after decimal come with decimal like ".52"  or ".2" but I need "52" or "2" without decimal.

Comment: did u try my comment?

Comment: Is it so difficult to [Remove the first character of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945548)? (Or just try Avinash Raj's solution)

Comment: @BhargavRao: Well, then I think just use Avinash's way is better than get `.52`, remove the `.`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Yep, That's what I commented