# How to remove the first character of a string that's in a list? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, arrays, string

I would like to remove the ["flow", "flappy", "flirtify"] first character from every single index in this array, but I don't know how. I tried almost everything but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? Add the code and someone will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be list comprehension

```py
l = [e[1:] for e in ["flow", "flappy", "flirtify"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

to remove the first character of a string you can just use string[1:] who return you the same string without the first character.

see code example below :

```
for myword in myWordsArray:
  print(myword[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first_char_removed = [word[1:] for word in original_list]
```

In the future, I would recommend posting your code attempts

Answer (score 0):

```
[word[1:] for word in ["flow", "flappy", "flirtify"]]
```

you can see how to do it for a [single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945548/remove-the-first-character-of-a-string), and then use list comprehension